# doing Durbin-Wu-Hausman Test manually using r

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am trying to compute the Wu-Hausman test manually without the need to use any function.
The test involves a two-step procedure. Firstly, we pick the variable that is assumed to be endogenous and regress it on a set of control variables:

```
equation (1): endogenous= bX1 +bX2 + bX3 + e
```

the resulting residuals from the regression will be saved (R-equation 1). Secondly, the original model will be regressed with endogenous, the control variables, as well as the saved
residuals (R-equation 1) from the first stage regression.

```
equation (2): y= endogenous + R-equation 1 + bX1 +bX2 + bX3 + e
```

If the coefficient on the saved residuals (R-equation 1) is significant, then it can be concluded that the endogenous variable is endogenously related to the dependent variable.

my question is that when I apply `equation (2)` I face a collinearity problem as VIF function gives this error message "there are aliased coefficients in the model". I need to know if I am doing something wrong or there is something I am missing here.